# Error in my simple python script

Tags: python, input

I have made this script in python:

```
a=raw_input("Enter your Name here:")
b=raw_input("Enter Your Country Name here:")
c=input("Enter Your Phone Number Here:")
```

--->The problem is when i enter a number like 123456 it gives no error but when i enter 123456789 or 0682020687 it gives an error.

Can someone explain why this happens and how to solve this?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Also, if this is indeed python 2 (raw_input) the final input will be trying to be executed, which may cause the error. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Enter Your Phone Number Here:0680004637
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script1.py", line 6, in <module>
    c=input("Enter Your Phone Number Here:")
  File "<string>", line 1
    0680004637
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: With Python 2.x just always use raw_input and convert to a type as required (use `int(c)` for integers).  With Python 3.x, `input` is the same as `raw_input` in 2.x  (and raw_input is removed) and you can now just use input everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Starting a number with a zero marks it as octal in Python 2.x. If you want phone numbers starting with 0, you should get the phone number as a string as well, use `raw_input`:

```
c = raw_input("Enter Your Phone Number Here:")
```

The problem occurs because you are not allowed to use 8 in an octal number. So 0682020687 would raise an error. 123456789 shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yeah 123456879 is not an issue anymore.
Okay so if i want to have a phone number like 0682020687 what would be the code?

Comment: Get it as string as well. `c = raw_input("Enter Your Phone Number Here:")`

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is using `input` instead of `raw_input` for the last line.

As the documentation says, `input` will cause the input to be evaluated with `eval` and as Faruk Sahin says, this will cause the number to be evaluated as an octal, of which 0682020687 is not a valid octal number. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Change the last line to:

```
c = raw_input("Enter Your Phone Number Here:")
```

Which will read the input as a string and store it in the variable, `c`. (Much like you have been doing in the first two lines)

Once you've got that string, you can turn it into a number using the `int` function:

```
c = int(raw_input("Enter Your Phone Number Here:"))
```

If the input is not a valid integer, it will throw an exception which you can catch. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

You should also note that if you switch to using python 3, you will need to replace all the `raw_input` functions with `input` which does the same as `raw_input` did in python 2. See: http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Tom Leese
I am a begginer but from what i have read input() is used for numbers and raw_input for strings.

Comment: No, if you want numbers, you should use `c = int(raw_input("Enter Your Phone Number Here:"))` which will turn the input string into an integer (whole number).